# Mongodb rearrange or move a value of a field in collection

Tags: mongodb, pymongo

I have a small collection of tasks that each have their own execution priority. I want to be able to insert a new task with given priority or move a task to different priority.

These actions should cause other priorities to align themselves.
I'm using mongodb + python (pymongo), my question is there a way to (efficiently) achieve this using mongodb itself or I better do it programmatically and update all records afterward?

For example we start with the following set of tasks:

```
[
    {'name': 'task_a', 'priority': 1},
    {'name': 'task_b', 'priority': 2},
    {'name': 'task_c', 'priority': 3},
]
```

Now if I add another task, say: `{'name': 'task_d', 'priority': 2}`.
I need my collections to look like this (priorities updated accordingly):

```
[
    {'name': 'task_a', 'priority': 1},
    {'name': 'task_b', 'priority': 3},
    {'name': 'task_c', 'priority': 4},
    {'name': 'task_d', 'priority': 2},
]
```

Or if I change the priority of a task to higher or lower, say: `task_a -> 3` I need my collection to look like this:

```
[
    {'name': 'task_a', 'priority': 3},
    {'name': 'task_d', 'priority': 1},
    {'name': 'task_b', 'priority': 2},
    {'name': 'task_c', 'priority': 4},
]
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do it like this.

```
db.collection.update({
  "name": "task_d"
},
{
  "$set": {
    "name": "task_d",
    "priority": 1
  }
},
{
  "multi": false,
  "upsert": true,
  "$sort": {
    "name": 1
  }
})
```

Comment: If only it was that simple :)

Comment: I have tried it with your json example can do it yourself also https://mongoplayground.net/

Comment: Please notice the value of the `priority` field. It's not about the `name`.

Comment: As far as I understood if there is a task_b with priority of 1 this should come second and task_a with prioprity 2 should come first?

Comment: No, it's not about the order (order doesn't matter at all), it's about the value of the field `priority`.

Comment: Alright can check now I have edited the post